# MVC 5 how to work with custom URLs or Url Rewriting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a gallery website. That developed in asp.net. Now I want to port it to asp.net MVC5. While doing it I run into an issue without solving it I cant go into further development. So here is the requirements:

a) Every gallery has its own independent folder and has photos in it. the url for the photo galleries will be: `localhost/gallery1`, `localhost/gallery2` and so on.

b) Each gallery has two types of layouts and options the commbo is given bellow:

```
localhost/gallery1/still/grid
localhost/gallery1/still/slide
localhost/gallery1/gifs/grid
localhost/gallery1/gifs/slide
```

c) change of [gallery1] to any other name should serve the photos from within the new name folder.

d) we also have a way to configure gallery for each folder by accessing admin

```
localhost/gallery1/admin
localhost/gallery2/admin
```

I am new to MVC. And I dont know how to work with that... I just created a brand new MVC5 project using Visual Studio with builtin example. Can anyone help me how to deal with this?

**EDIT:**
The controller has to be a universal control for anything immediately after `localhost/` so in my example urls `gallery1` and `gallery2` or anything like that will be caught by a universal controller, may be `GalleryController`.

After the name of the gallery, the next two url segments are going to work in conjugation. I am not sure how to catch them in a universal controller and then segment them out on the basis of what is after `still` and `gifs`.

Comment: You need to understand how routing works in ASP.NET MVC.
This link might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: @BurakKarakuş, thanks for the link. Its going to be very helpful in this regard. Well I actually understand the basics but not that advance I have stated. May be after reading the suggested article I might be able to solve it.

Comment: I'm sure it will help, because it has similar examples like that you asked about.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş, hmm i am reading the article, but looks like I dont find the solution from it... I am updating my question please read the edit.

Comment: I saw your edit, I guess I'll try to answer tomorrow, since it is almost morning here where I live.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş, thanks buddy. I will wait. btw, morning for me too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114486/discussion-between-kmx-and-burak-karakus).

Answer (score 2):

I have found answer to my own question. Here is what i did.

Inside RouteConfig.cs I simply added following mapping:-

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Dynamic",
                url: "{name}/{action}/{layout}",
                defaults: 
                new { 
                       controller = "Gallery", 
                       action = "Display" , 
                       layout = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
```

This is how my `GalleryController.cs` looks like:

```
public class GalleryController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Gallery
        public ActionResult   Display()
        {

            return View("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Admin()
        {    
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Gifs()
        {
            if(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("gifs/slide"))
                return View("GifsSlide");
            else
                return View("GifsGrid");
        }

        public ActionResult Still()
        {
            if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("stil/slide"))
                return View("StillSlide");
            else
                return View("StillGrid");
        }
    }
```

Inside my Gallery folder in Views I have following .cshtml structure

```
Views/Gallrey/gifsgrid.cshtml
Views/Gallrey/gifsslide.cshtml
Views/Gallrey/stillgrid.cshtml
Views/Gallrey/stillslide.cshtml
Views/Gallrey/admin.cshtml
```

**Achievement:**

```
localhost/gallery1/still/grid
localhost/gallery1/still/slide
localhost/gallery1/gifs/grid
localhost/gallery1/gifs/slide
localhost/gallery1/admin
```

Comment: This was exact the same answer that I was thinking to write today, glad that you figured it out. :)

Comment: @BurakKarakuş, thanks mate. So I am on the right path. Well after that finding I have managed to use full potential of MVC5 and my App is looking so good. thanks for that article bro.